# Porque está retornando NaN?

Tags: javascript

Estou preso em um exercício cujo não consigo me libertar, gostaria de saber o porquê está retornando NaN, acredito que esteja dando alguma encrenca no função "sorteia", porém não estou conseguindo ver qual.

```js
    var mostraBR = function(frase){
  document.write(frase + "<br/>")
 }
 
 var mostraHR = function(frase){
  document.write(frase + "<hr/>")
 }

 var sorteia = function(x){
  var n = Math.round(Math.random * x);
  return n;
 }

 var numeroPensado = sorteia(10);

 var chute = prompt("Já Pensei. Qual número você acha que é?");
 if (chute == numeroPensado) {
  mostraHR("Você acertou, pois eu pensei no " + numeroPensado);
 } else {
  mostraBR("Você errou, eu tinha pensado no " + numeroPensado);
 }

 if (chute < numeroPensado) {
  mostraBR("Número " + chute + " é menor que " + numeroPensado);
 } else {
  mostraBR("Número " + chute + " é maior que " + numeroPensado);
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, o problema é na função de sorteio. Você está tentando multiplicar a própria função `Math.random`, e não o valor de retorno dela. O correto seria:

```
var sorteia = function(x){
    var n = Math.round(Math.random() * x);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, foi só na hora de escrever o Math.random que esqueci dos parenteses...

Answer (score 1):

Você apenas errou na hora de declarar o `Math.ramdom()`.

Não se preocupe, todos passamos por isso quando estávamos estudando, é errando que se aprende ;)

```js
var mostraBR = function(frase){
  document.write(frase + "<br/>")
 }
 
 var mostraHR = function(frase){
  document.write(frase + "<hr/>")
 }

 var sorteia = function(x){
        x = Number(x)
  var n = Math.round(Math.random() * x)
        
  return n;
 }

 var numeroPensado = sorteia(10);

 var chute = prompt("Já Pensei. Qual número você acha que é?");
 if (chute == numeroPensado) {
  mostraHR("Você acertou, pois eu pensei no " + numeroPensado);
 } else {
  mostraBR("Você errou, eu tinha pensado no " + numeroPensado);
 }

 if (chute < numeroPensado) {
  mostraBR("Número " + chute + " é menor que " + numeroPensado);
 } else {
  mostraBR("Número " + chute + " é maior que " + numeroPensado);
 }
```

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, foi um descuido daqueles...